# Remove first character from list of names and rename

Tags: powershell

I have a list of users whose names start with the old naming convention which is first character and surname i.e ASmith, BJones, CGrayson etc and I need to remove the first character, so that I'm just left with surname, which I will then query AD with to extract first and lastname, however I was unable to rename the list. I tried this code, but can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
$name = get-content c:\tempfiles\list.txt
foreach ($name in $names) 
{
  $th = $name.substring(1);
  rename-item $name -newname $th
} | export-csv C:\TempFiles\New.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in the first line of your code (you want the collection of names to go in to $names and then analyze each one in to the variable $name as part of your loop):

```
$names = get-content c:\tempfiles\list.txt
```

However in order for ForEach to support the pipeline you need to use ForEach-Object instead so the next section should be:

```
$names | ForEach-Object {
  $th = $_.substring(1);
  write-output $th
} | Set-content c:\tempfiles\newfile.txt
```

You also don't need to use Rename-Item, that's for renaming a file or other object retrieved via a namespace provider. Just output the new string with write-output and then use the pipeline to output it to a new text file.

If you want the result to go to a CSV file, and you want that file to also contain the old name, you could do something like this:

```
$names | ForEach-Object {

    $Properties = [ordered]@{
        'oldname' = $_
        'newname' = $_.substring(1)
    }

    New-Object -Property $Properties -TypeName PSCustomObject

} | export-csv New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

In this example we build a hashtable that has two properties (oldname and newname) and then create an object that has those properties which is then passed through the pipeline to export-csv.

Comment: sorry, pressed enter.. grrr.. the file outputs number of length not the surnames :(

Comment: Is list.txt just a list of the usernames and nothing else?

Comment: Hi it works to a text file.. I can work with that .. thanks for your help  :)

Comment: There was a dot in them where some were duplicates i.e david jones and dave jones

Comment: No worries, in order to use export-csv i think we'd need to build an object within the loop beyond a simple string.

Comment: But even without the dots it still gives a numerical value.. strange .. oh well onwards and upwards :)

Comment: Is that using $var =@{} and then at the end $var | export-csv

Comment: I have extended my answer to show how you might get CSV output.

Comment: Thanks again Mark .. really appreciate it  :)